# When loading an OBJ i get this

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, sfml, wavefront

and this time i have loaded a model successfully! yay!!

but theres a slight problem, one that i had with another obj loader...

heres what it looks like:

http://img132.imageshack.us/i/newglitch2.jpg/

heres another angle if u cant see it right away:

http://img42.imageshack.us/i/newglitch3.jpg/

now this is supposed to look like a cube, but as you can see, the edges of the faces on the cube are being very choppy

is anyone else having this problem, or if anyone knows how to solve this then let me know

also comment if theres any code that needs to be shown, ill be happy to post it.

hey i played around with the code(changed some stuff) and this is what i have come up with

ORIGINAL:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(50.f,(double)800 / (double)600,0.f,200.f);
    glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, -10.0f);
```

result: choopy image(look at images)

CURRENT:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    gluPerspective(50.f,(double)800 / (double)600,0.f,200.f);
    glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, -50.0f);
    glLoadIdentity();
```

result: model is not choppy but cannot move camera(model is right in front of me)

Comment: gluPrespective belongs into the projection matrix, not the modelview.

Comment: Don't remove contents like that, it's not a game. You cause the answers to become meaningless - please rollback and if you have new questions related to the original question **add** them to the question.

Comment: images not working and i dont have them with me.......heres the new question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380314/i-see-some-transparency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gluPerspective(50.f,(double)800 / (double)600,0.f,200.f);
                                              ^^^ 
                                               | 
That's your problem right there ---------------+
```

The near clip distance must be greater than 0 for perspective projections. Actually you should choose near to be as far away as possible and the far clip plane to be as near as possible.

Say your depth buffer is 16 bits wide, then you slice the scene into 32768 slices. The slice distribution follows a 1/x law. Technically you're dividing by zero.

Comment: and thats with the original? or the changed(current)

Answer (score 0):

Well this looks like a projection setting issue. Some parts of your cube, when transformed into clip space, exceed near/far planes.

From what I see you are using orthogonal projection matrix - it's standard for making 2D UI. Please review nearVal and farVal of your [glOrtho](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) call. For 2D UI they are usually set as -1 and 1 respectively (or 0 and 1), so may want to either [scale down](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glScale.3G.html) cube or increase view frustum depth by modifying mentioned parameters.

Comment: hmm...actually i didnt even use a glOrtho call in my project..is there a certain place where i should set this up?(like if i call it by itself or use it in a certain object like "object.glOrtho()"

Comment: if it would be an projection issue, then object wouldn't be cut like it is on both screenshots, just look at top face at second screenshot. projection won't cut your face like that.

Comment: Try scaling down this cube and then we will have an answer whether it's a projection matrix issue or not.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: u mean make it smaller?

Comment: also my distance is from 0-100 and i only moved the camera back about 10 units. the cube is about 3-5 units in size

Comment: i also had this problem with heiko robins' obj2opengl....what if i call a different matrix?

Comment: Great you fixed your projection matrix, but could you please not remove original post's content when editing? This whole discussion is out of context right now.